# fixed english language for my android app

Tags: android

when I change my phone language English to Jordan. my all design start from the right. So that my design changed. How can I fixed this language problem? That my design never break. How can I set my app language English only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 4.2 or above a simple method available.

You can set the `android:layoutDirection` property in XML with value `rtl` or `ltr`.

The property overrides the value of `android:supportsRtl` property in application block your manifest file.

Below 4.2 you can use `android:supportsRtl="false"` under application block of your manifest file.

Comment: can you explain more. where i have to set this??

Comment: yah its work...............and thank you so much......... I am really so happy. And really so glad to meed you.

Comment: Welcome, same here!

Comment: bro i have another question can u help me??

Comment: Yaa sure please provide the link for that